# Determining an Output Capacitor Value for LED Driver

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, led-strip

I'm designing a buck LED circuit using a [LED2000PUR (Data sheet)](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LED2000PUR-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-21217168.pdf). The issue that I am having is that the LED I'm designing for doesn't have a data sheet, and I need to determine the dynamic resistance so that I can select an appropriate output capacitor. The only parameters that I know, is the LED runs off of 3.6 V and has an If of 1.39 A.

[Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000096405458.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.17.53277434IUiWix&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.33416.213724.0&scm_id=1007.33416.213724.0&scm-url=1007.33416.213724.0&pvid=c477c0e6-bcef-414d-b821-3063134171c0&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.33416.213724.0,pvid:c477c0e6-bcef-414d-b821-3063134171c0,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238113%231998&&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sceneId%22:%2223416%22,%22sku_id%22:%2210000000252565664%22%7D) is the link for what I am designing for.

Information about dynamic resistance can be found on page 15 and information about inductor and output capacitor selection can be found on page 22 of the datasheet.

My system will run off of 5 V from a powerbank.

Below is an equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVSOpR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The manufacturer has a tool on their website where entering the input voltages and LED specifications will output recommended components. I've preferred this as I'm not an Electrical Engineer and I find the data sheet to be oddly written.

My observations from manipulating the values are:

- Cout capacity and voltage decrease when Rd increases
- Cout values decrease when LED ripple percentage increases
- Cout values decrease and L values increase when Il Ripple percentage increases

[image: Schematic LED2000]

Comment: Unless that's a UV LED  , it's an odd looking LED Vf, If, but typically at 5W it has an Rd ~ 1/2Pd or 100 mOhms.  Show LED P/N & link in Q.

Comment: The datasheet contains a method for determining the LED dynamic resistance at the operating point. Have you tried that method?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 How so? White LEDs can have Vf from 3 to 5. The LED is from an AliExpress seller. It's packaged with a lens, and I've asked the seller for data sheets and information about it, but they have just provided me wattage and other optical characteristics like lux etc.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble, no datasheet, no sale.

Comment: @Justme the data sheet says “If the LED data sheet does not report the equivalent resistor value, it can be simply derived 
as the tangent to the diode I-V characteristic in the present working point” I don't have a I-V characteristic graph. But if I'm understanding correctly, the Rd value can be determined from I/V, so 1.4/3.6 = 0.39 ohms

Comment: @MechFlag Incorrect. First of all you calculated resistance as R=I/V while it is R=V/I. Second, that gives you the equivalent resistance of the bias point (2.57 ohms), not the dynamic resistance at the bias point which is the tangent (dV/dI) drawn on the I-V curve at the bias point as explained in the datasheet.

Comment: The actual forward voltage of a white led is about 2.7-3.3v, with higher values usually corresponding to lower quality parts. If you're buying a part with no datasheet and the only thing the seller will tell you is that the forward voltage is unusually poor, that probably means you're buying low quality parts, factory rejects, etc. This is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @user1850479 I've updated the post with a link to the LED I have chosen. I need the collimation aspect of it, hence why I've selected that one.

Comment: Those LEDs are > 3V are very low quality , low lumens/watt and poor choice , be wise and choose power LEDs with better specs , I was an expert in creating custom LED specs and sold over 1 million in 10 yrs https://tinyurl.com/wfpdpyez  Choose from here

Comment: If you see 6V that means two whites in series on same substrate. The threshold is approx 2.8V and incremental Rd is above this. Lower Rd for same lumens is better efficacy

Comment: BTW if you sustained 4W in your link, the plastic would melt since there was no heatsink

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I agree with you 100%. I have already selected a high quality LED; but selecting a lens, manufacturing an enclosure, MCPCB, and curing filter, would be too expensive and time-consuming. But that is all beyond the scope of this question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps all you need is a common mini 10W LED Torch complete with battery , zoom lens

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No use, I'm trying to make a surgical headlight.

Comment: Then you will have to figure out how to spread that much heat on the head or use fibre optics.  I have a single LED solution , is also  used in 32 LED arrays on MCPCB for Ambulance/fire engines that works very well with just one LED. Just one is  blinding to look at .   You'll want CCT around 4500'K 150 klux or a tight XY limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130498/discussion-between-mechflag-and-tony-stewart-ee75).

Comment: Example of a toy lamp of poor quality. high contrast,  with shadows , eye fatigue and poor CCT, CRI  , Iv intensity,  etc...  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000874378434.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.1.488c270fCI9vo5&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=b0a08ada-3239-436d-bde8-ec33656330fd&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:b0a08ada-3239-436d-bde8-ec33656330fd,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238108%231977&&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sceneId%22:%223339%22,%22sku_id%22:%2210000010059230641%22%7D

Answer (score 2):

Measure the dynamic resistance as per the instructions in the datasheet.

Plot a I-V curve of your LED around the bias point and draw a tangent at the bias point to have a line with dV/dI.

Then you can calculate a value for the capacitor.

Comment: This might be a basic question, but it is lost on me. After finding the bias point to be 2.57 ohms, how can I plot a I-V curve if I have no other information about the LED except for its voltage and forward current?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong for 2.57 Ohms for a VI=P= 4 W LED , @MechFlag  that would be the linear R equivalent, not the exponential LED slope

Comment: @MechFlag You need to do the plot by measuring LED current and voltage at different bias points yourself. For example use a lab power supply and adjust the the current slightly up and down and see the change in voltage. Or adjust the voltage slightly up and down to see change in current.